# Having profiles for minimum services on windows

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface

My Problem: On windows surface, there are number of programs/services that run all the time, causing battery drainage ( I assume ).. I was wondering if there is program tool that can shut done all the services/running background process when not needed?
for example, I have Sql Server , Office sign, COM+ services etc running all the times, I dont need network services while watching something that is already downloaded, or audio services running if I am just programming or reading only.

I assume there would be a tool that would have the minimum services required with windows like in the safe mood.

Comment: What operating system is your surface running? Windows 10 has gotten better at power management. Do you have any evidence that these services are causing a drain on your battery? Without it, i don't think it is accurate to suggest a "running" service is draining power when it could be completely idle. If it's not idle then it is needed, thus defeating the purpose.

Comment: with a custom script u can stop specific services. u build a list based on your useage like stop sql etc etc for when u r watching a movie.

Comment: @Appleoddity : assummed the more things run the more power is consumed, thank you for the suggestion, should totally have the system run with the least number of everthing running in the background and see how long the battery lasts, and then turn them on to see what causes the most drain, for example having wifi or blue tooth on definitely causes faster drain.

Comment: Correct. Things like wifi and Bluetooth do cause drainage. That is why airplane mode is provided though. No need to get fancy. :)

Comment: @Appleoddity : try being in a place where were there are not many outlets and you have wait for your turn to re-charge! back in the normal city I never cared about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP was the last Windows OS to have Hardware Profiles, which was what you'd use to build distinct service profiles (a la [Blackviper](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/)).

You can use Devcon from the Windows Developers Kit to create hardware profiles, but there is also no longer a way to assign service states to a specific profile, so this wouldn't help either.

The long and short of this is that you can no longer create pre-configured service groups using hardware profiles, and you haven't been able to for a while.

As others have commented, it is very unnecessary to do so these days, as services and the general optimization of the Windows OS has made this unnecessary to a great extent.

Comment: I guess I need to programttically find the running services , and turn them on and off.

Comment: You could do this with individual user accounts and login scripts, or a selector menu that ran scripts based on your selection.